# How to open the Windows Terminal in new tab from File Explorer

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-terminal

I know you can open Windows Terminal from the same folder by typing `wt` in the address bar.
But if I want to open another instance of the terminal but in a new tab, and not a new window of the terminal, is there a way to do it?

`Windows 10, Version 10.10.19043`

`Windows Terminal version 1.11.2921.0`

Also, `wt -d` throws an error: `"1 required TEXT missing.."` so I can't open it from current directory but instead it opens from `C:/Users/user`

Comment: Updated the post, thank you. Also noticed there are more issues with this version now: `wt -d` throws an error so I can't open from current directory

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
wt -w 0 -d folder
```

The parameter `-w` is defined as:

> -w,--window TEXT
>
> Specify a terminal window to run the given commandline in. "0" always
> refers to the current window.

Comment: thank you. I get error: `[error 0x8007010b when launching 'powershell.exe']`
Could not access starting directory `"C:\folder"`

Comment: The folder is written wrongly. Can you include here your exact command?

Comment: OH wait, I thought folder is the command, but now I realized you mean I need to specify my own folder name? But I want to be able to do something like just typing cmd in the address bar of the folder, not specifying a folder

Comment: The folder is already in the field where you're typing the command, so just go to its beginning and type `wt -w 0 -d `. Quotes will be required if the folder name contains blanks.

Comment: I get the same error with `wt -w 0 -d`: `--startingDirectory: 1 required TEXT missing. Run with --help for more information`

Comment: Did you write `-d:` ? Remove the colon. If not, please give the *entire* contents of the field.

Comment: Yes! It works with the `:`. So there is no simple way as using `cmd`, right? (just typing `wt`)

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. This works well on my side with a command that looks like `wt -w 0 -d C:\Temp`.

Comment: I want to be able to launch a terminal from the same folder in a simple way as typing `cmd` from the address bar of folder you're in

Comment: The simplest command to use will be `wt -w 0 -d .`, which will work for the current folder (`.`). As another idea, create a System environment variable called `wt` that contains `wt -w 0 -d .` and use `%wt%`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open in current window in new tab and not create a new instance, use:

```
--window 0 new-tab --startingDirectory .
```

- `.` means current directory
- `0` means current window

The whole command means:
*Open a new tab with the default profile in the current window with path of current directory*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).